# Why does calling the variable name 'name' make ',' an element in my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var name = ["a","b","c"]
alert(name[1])
//alert will return ,
```

if i change `name` to `array` or `var` to `let`, the code will return `b` normally. Why does this happen?

Comment: it is a reserved property of `window`. please see above link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still don't understand why ```let``` allows me to name my variable ```name``` without any problem

Comment: `let` creates a local scope. the variables from the outer scope with the same name are not available.  in this case you get a new variable and this allows to chage the content of it.